# Can layout and logic separated in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I understand presence Bloc and Scoped Model in flutter.
But that isn't separate like a layout file in java's SpringBoot.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually separate layout and logic in flutter. I have an example.

In my `LoginForm` I have a function

```
_attemptLogin() {
    BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context).add(
      LoginButtonPressed(
        context: context,
        email: _tecEmail.text,
        password: _tecPassword.text,
      ),
    );
  }
```

called by

```
RaisedButton(
color: Colors.blue,
child: const Text(
    'Login',
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
    ),
),
onPressed: (state is LoginProcessing)
    ? null
    : _attemptLogin,
),
```

and in my `LoginBloc`, I have the ff code inside mapEventToState

```
  @override
Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(LoginEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginButtonPressed) {
        yield LoginProcessing();

        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 250));

        try {
        var loginResponse =
            await _attemptLogin(userRepository, event.email, event.password);

        /// Get Firebase Token
        final firebaseToken =
            await Provider.of<FirebaseMessagingProvider>(context).getToken();

        if (loginResponse['data'] != null && firebaseToken != null) {
            User user =
                _setUserFromJsonMap(context, loginResponse['data']['user']);
            IdentityToken identityToken = _setIdentityTokenFromJsonMap(
                context, loginResponse['data']['token']);

            /// Request Firebase Token Update
            var jsonCreateUserFirebaseTokenResponse =
                await _attemptFirebaseTokenUpdate(context, firebaseToken);

            if (jsonCreateUserFirebaseTokenResponse != null) {
            authBloc.add(LoggedIn(identityToken: identityToken));

            yield LoginInitial();
            }
        } else {
            yield LoginFailure(message: 'Login failed.');
        }
        } catch (error, stackTrace) {
        print(error);
        print(stackTrace);

        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        yield LoginFailure(
            message: 'Login failed. Please check your internet connection.');
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't include all the other functions/classes as I have already deleted several lines of code to make it look readable, since it contains a ton of code already; which is unnecessary for only trying to prove a point that you can actually separate code for your view and logic.

Comment: Note that this isn't the best case scenario, since I can make another class/controller and transfer some codes inside the bloc function to other controllers to make the bloc class look cleaner. I was in a rush when doing this code tho, so it looks like that.

Comment: This is a just Bloc. and It`s for each states rather than separating business logics, sure it can separate also but